# vCalendar/iCal show Free/Busy in calendar

Tags: php, icalendar, vcalendar

I am using iCalendar to export my appointments to google, outlook. I am stucked at how to set parameter as free/busy so that when the user views it can get to know that it's a busy or free schedule.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140323T075626Z
DTSTART:20140323
SUMMARY:Call one
UID:
DESCRIPTION:.
LOCATION:.
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking at the TRANSP property (value = OPAQUE for busy, and TRANSPARENT for free). See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.7

I imagine that is is a work in progress but your UID should not be empty. Having a meaningful PRODID also helps.

Comment: So setting this to a recurring event, for example every Monday of week from 8AM-5PM, TRANSP=TRANSPARENT, would mark this event as free time ? AKA I'm trying to mark opening hours of a store, [see my qeustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58413821/icalendar-opening-hours)