# iCalendar Opening Hours

Tags: frequency, icalendar, caldav

How do you write a `FREQ` rule in `iCalendar` data format for store's opening hours ?

Let's say the store is open every working day (Mon-Fri):

1. from 8:00AM to 5:00PM
2. (or with lunch break from) 8:00AM to 11:00AM and 12:00PM to 5:00PM

This would solve the days: `FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=MO;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR`, how about the hours though ?

**Edit:**
Could I do sth like this?

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970902T080000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=MO;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
DURATION=PT9H
```

Would this mean every day from Monday to Friday, from 8:00AM till 5:00PM (thanks to duration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved it with `DTSTART` and `DTEND` like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
DTSTAMP:20191016T133700Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20191007T080000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20191007T170000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
SUMMARY:Opening hours without lunch break
...
END:VEVENT
```

And I think if I wanted to have opening hours with a lunch break, I'd have to create two separate events.

I believe using `DURATION` (as mentioned in Question) would also be an option:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
DTSTAMP:20191016T133700Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Bratislava:20191007T080000
DURATION:PT9H
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
SUMMARY:Opening hours without lunch break
...
END:VEVENT
```

**Edit:**

This however marks an event in calendar, I'd like this time to be marked as `free` time probably. Maybe sth with `FREEBUSY` ?

**Edit 2:**
Setting `TRANSP:TRANSPARENT` marks this event as free time in a calendar (or "not busy")